# Calculating which drawn circle is the nearest to another one

Tags: java, android, position, distance, geometry

i want to get the x and y of the circle with the lowest distance to my special circle. I am creating 25 circles with a timer and need to check every drawn circle on the field. What I already have is this:

```
protected void onDraw (android.graphics.Canvas canvas){

    //If arrow-button was clicked, do ... get the circle with the lowest distance to viking circle
    if (buttonClicked == true) {
        //distance of the current circle from the viking
        int tempCircleDistance = 0;

        //the minimum distance we have found so far in our loop
        int minCircleDistance = 0;

        //index of the min circle we have found so far
        int indexOfNearest=0;
        for(int i = 0; i<circlesOnTheField; i++) 
        {
            //help me Phytagoras
            tempCircleDistance = (int) (Math.sqrt((viking.getX() - circles.get(i).getX())*
                    (viking.getX() - circles.get(i).getX())+
                    (viking.getY() - circles.get(i).getY())*
                    (viking.getY() - circles.get(i).getY()))-
                    (viking.getR() + circles.get(i).getR()));
          //first cycle or did we find the nearest circle? If so update our variables
            if(i==0||tempCircleDistance<minCircleDistance)
            {    
                   indexOfNearest=i;
                   minCircleDistance=tempCircleDistance;
            }
        }
        if(circles.get(indexOfNearest).getIsDrawn() == true) {

            //draw the line with the given index of the nearest circle
            //At this point, nearest circle is calculated and we draw a line from viking to that circle
            canvas.drawLine(viking.getX(), viking.getY(), 
                            circles.get(indexOfNearest).getX(), 
                            circles.get(indexOfNearest).getY(), 
                            pgoal);
            //Here we delete the circle and increase our variable frags for one more killed opponent.
            deleteCircle(circles.get(indexOfNearest));
            circlesOnTheField--;
            frags++;
            buttonClicked = false;
        }
     }
    //END

    //This is where the circles are drawn
    for(int k = 0; k<circlesOnTheField; k++) {
            canvas.drawCircle(circles.get(k).getX(), circles.get(k).getY(), circles.get(k).getR(), p3);
            circles.get(k).setIsDrawn(true);
    }
}
```

So I store my circles in the array called `circles[]` and have my fixed second circle `viking` to calculate the distance to. The variable `arrowCircle` should store the name of the nearest circle. Then I want to draw a line between the nearest circle to the viking circle.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks in advance
I think the part with `if(i>=1) {...` might be incorrect.

Edited 21.09.15:

This is what happens on `deleteCircle()`:

```
    public static void deleteCircle(Circle circle) {
    circles.remove(circle);
    circlesOnTheField--;
}
```

And the `addCircle()`:

```
    public static void addCircle() {
    if(circlesOnTheField >= 25) {
        circlesOnTheField = 25;
    }
    else{
    circlesOnTheField++;
    }
}
```

I have one timer which executes `addCircle()` and another one with `moveCircle()`:

```
public static void moveCircle() {
    for(int i=0; i<circlesOnTheField; i++) {
        //Move circles downwards
        circles.get(i).setY(circles.get(i).getY()+5);

        //Check if the circle collides with the viking
        if(detectCollision(viking, circles.get(i))) {
            deleteCircle(circles.get(i));
            circles.get(i).setIsDrawn(false);
            life--;
        }

        //Check if the circle intersects the goal line and recreate it if yes
        if(intersects(circles.get(i).getX(), circles.get(i).getY(), circles.get(i).getR(), 0, 750, 500, 760)) {
            deleteCircle(circles.get(i));
            circles.get(i).setIsDrawn(false);
            circlesInGoal++;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, this is what is executed in the constructor:

```
public static void createNewCircleOnCanvas() {
    //Collision Detection
    circles.clear();
    int createdCircles = 0;
     outer: while (createdCircles < 25) {
        int randomX = r.nextInt(500);
        int randomY = r.nextInt(300);
       candidate = new Circle(randomX, randomY, 33, "Circle"+createdCircles, false);
        inner: for (int z = 0; z<createdCircles;z++) {
            //If new created circle collides with any already created circle or viking, continue with outer
              if (detectCollision(candidate, circles.get(z))) continue outer;
        }
       circles.add(candidate);
       createdCircles++;
    }
```

Comment: In the `if(i>=1) {...` part, why are you only checking if `circleDistances[i]` is smaller then the previous one and not smaller then **all** the other distances? The circle should only be assigned to `arrowCircle` iff the distance from the circle to your special circle is smaller then the distance of any other circle to the special circle.

Comment: I thought it should work if I begin with the first circle and only look at the next one, because it should always be a smaller value, right?

Comment: Consider following : Draw special circle. Afterwards draw second circle, call it A. Assume it's distance to the special circle is 5 (according to some definition of distance). Now draw a third & fourth circle, respectively B and C. After drawing B check it's distance against A's distance. Let's assume B had a distance of 7 to the special circle, so **A is still the closest**. After drawing C we check it's distance against that of B, let's assume C had a distance of 6, then `distance(C) < distance(B)`. However still check it against A, else it would falsely result in C being the closest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming getR() gives the radius?!
Then try this instead of your for loop:

```
//distance of the current circle from the viking
int tempCircleDistance = 0;

//the minimum distance we have found so far in our loop
int minCircleDistance = 0;

//index of the min circle we have found so far
int indexOfNearest=0;

for(int i = 0; i<circlesOnTheField; i++) 
{
        //help me Phytagoras
        tempCircleDistance = (int) (Math.sqrt((viking.getX() - circles[i].getX())*
                                              (viking.getX() - circles[i].getX())+
                                              (viking.getY() - circles[i].getY())*
                                              (viking.getY() - circles[i].getY()))-
                                              (viking.getR() + circles[i].getR()));

        //first cycle or did we find the nearest circle? If so update our variables
        if(i==0||tempCircleDistance<minCircleDistance)
        {    
               indexOfNearest=i;
               minCircleDistance=tempCircleDistance;
        }
}

//draw the line with the given index of the nearest circle
canvas.drawLine(viking.getX(), viking.getY(), 
                circles[indexOfNearest].getX(), 
                circles[indexOfNearest].getY(), 
                pgoal);
```

just copy paste and it will magically work ╰( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° )つ──☆*:・ﾟ

No need to go through the Array twice, just hold the index of the nearest circle in a variable

Comment: Wow you're a magician :D! It is really working haha! I'm just thinking about a new idea. Can I use the line as a vector and move a bitmap with predefined speed (and if possible rotating) towards the nearest circle using this vector? Just thoughts! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: probably yes. You have the starting and end point you have the length, nothing speaks against it.I assume like a projectile attacking the nearest circle or what?!

Comment: Right! Like a throwing axe!

Comment: just go ahead and try it make a vector class with the needed variables and try it out

Comment: Ok before trying that out, I have an issue with deleting the nearest circle. As long as I keep my delete method away, my viking circle gets a connection line to the nearest circle (who are moving down always). Then, when I put the delete in, the line is drawn to two or three circles very fast and sometimes killing a circle wich is drawn two seconds afterwards. Take a look at my edited code. Thanks

Comment: I think I dont understand how you "remove" a circle...Maybe you ask if Circle is destroyed before doing any calculations on it